# GWT Asynchronous Wait for Callback

Tags: java, asynchronous, async-await, gwt, gxt

Fairly new to GWT and Asynchronous Programming.

Reading through the [GWT documentation on RPC](https://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html) and based on that, I have 2 Asynchronous functions that I've implemented in my Java file.

There is a slight dependency between the 2. The idea is that Function A has the capability to use the data generated by Function B, but will still work regardless. This will allow Function A to be a bit flexible in running.
To that extend, I made an `if-else` statement to check whether Function A will use the data from Function B or otherwise.

From what I've seen however, they will both run in parallel with each other, so Function A will process regardless whether Function B is done, resulting in a problematic output. Function B, which does abit more processing, will usually complete only after Function A is completed.

How do I make it so that Function A will not run until Function B is completed, especially if the condition to use the results from Function B is fulfilled?

```
ExportData export = new ExportData();
final List<?> theResult = new ArrayList<Object>();

            try {
                CommonService.Util.getInstance().FunctionB(<inputData>, new AsyncCallback<List<?>>() {
                    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                        // TODO: Do something with errors.
                        caught.fillInStackTrace();
                      }
                      public void onSuccess(List<?> result){
                        for (Object model : result) { 
                            ((ExportData) theResult).addData((BaseModel)model);
                        }
                      }
                    }
                );

            } catch (ApplicationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            if (<inputData> != null)
            {
                for (Object model : theResult) {
                    export.addData((BaseModel)model);
                }
            }
            else{
                for (BaseModel model : <alternateResults>) {
                    export.addData(model);
                }
            }
            

            CommonService.Util.getInstance().FunctionA(export, WidgetUtils.FILE_DOWNLOAD_CALLBACK);
```

Comment: GWT is single threaded on client side. So you call FunctionB first and the rest of the code ist called directly. It will not wait for onfailure or onSuccess to complete. This happens asynchronously at some point of time. Because you don't know what happens on server side. Maybe the network is slow and what ever you can imagine. If you have a dependency between the B and A und have to call A in the onSuccess of B.